# How to center form request divs inside a main div container

Tags: jquery, html, css, centering

I have a main container with a search form on the left and another div container on the right. On the right container we find the form submit found values which are on another div (let's call it result div).

This is the CSS:

```
.main-container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;    
    width: 90vw;
    height: 85vh;
    background-color: #ff9933;
}


/*form inside main-container on the left*/

.form{ 
  float: left;
  width: 15vw;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  margin-left: 2vh;
  position: absolute;
}


/* results-container inside main-container on the right*/ 

.results-container{
    display: inline-block;      
    width: 70vw;
    float: right;
}

/* found results div inside it's container */

.result{
    display: inline-block;  
    width: 284px;
    height: 315px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here are some images to make you understand, thanks for your help
[image: What I currently have]
[image: What I want it to look like]

I'm not able to center results inside results-container. If I remove `display: inline-block;` everything is centered but not aligned (one result per row). If I let it this way, all results are stick to the left which is not the desired behaviour.

I'm open to anything like PHP jQuery or such. I though about counting `$sql` results and change positioning depending on results `count()` but that's not practical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this will work or not as I don't have a working JSfiddle or something to test it but try adding following  `text-align: center;` to your `.results-container` css block.

```
.results-container{
    display: inline-block;      
    width: 70vw;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: I was about to answer the same. I've got a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/65a08ofk

Comment: yep! `text-align: center` works almost all the time for me

Comment: I swear god I also tried that and it didn't work, It just centered text and not related stuff (images, styles etc) But NOW magically It works like a charm! Ty very much ^^

Answer (score 0):

For a better flexible approach, I'd recommend using flexbox:

Approach in general (heights/widths etc are just for the example's sake):

```
.container {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 600px;
    width: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.result {
  margin: 10px;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   background: red;
}
```

Mess around with the result widths and see how it changes accordingly while kept centered.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80kd6prw/)

Answer (score 0):

Move from floating to [flexing](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Use

```
display:flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
```

on results-container to start.